# lxml modify tags prevent

Tags: python, html, lxml

How to prevent lxml modify tags

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring

html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
root = fromstring(html)
print etree.tostring(root,encoding='utf-8')
```

it prints short version of tag

```
'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen/>'
```

how to prevent this? needed output

```
'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tostring()` with `method="html"`:

```
print etree.tostring(root.find('iframe'), encoding='utf-8', method="html")
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
>>>
>>> html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
>>> root = fromstring(html)
>>> print etree.tostring(root.find('iframe'), encoding='utf-8', method="html")
<iframe allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" height="315" src="" width="560"></iframe>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!